# Generate random numbers with rand() except number zero

Tags: c, random

I would like to generate random numbers between 1 and 25 with the method rand().

But I only know how to generate random numbers this way, which includes the number zero by default:

```
int r = rand() % 26 /* random int between 0 and 25 */
```

Anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple

```
int r = 1 + rand() % 25 /* random int between 1 and 25 */
```

but you should use this

```
int r = (int)(1.0 + 25.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX)
```

as mentioned in the comments, the second is the more robust way to generate random numbers see this [link](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Comment: This method may not work, depending on how strict requirements for uniformity are.

Comment: @void_ptr can you elaborate please.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html

Comment: The rand() generator and the % 25 does not align. This is an important technicality if you want fair number generation.

Comment: It worked for me though! Thank you. I'll use the 2nd method.

Comment: Over time you'll learn that "It worked" doesn't mean it's right. void_ptr is right that using the simple mod method (and the advanced bit of math you missed--adding 1) isn't quite uniform, though it's probably OK for 90% of uses (if you're just doing a simple game, selecting a random piece of music, etc.).

Comment: Why `(1.0 + RAND_MAX)`?